# Conditional Validation in Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, formik

I have an email field that only gets shown if a checkbox is selected (boolean value is `true`). When the form get submitted, I only what this field to be required if the checkbox is checked (boolean is true).

This is what I've tried so far:

```js
const validationSchema = yup.object().shape({
   email: yup
         .string()
         .email()
         .label('Email')
         .when('showEmail', {
             is: true,
             then: yup.string().required('Must enter email address'),
         }),
    })
```

I've tried several other variations, but I get errors from Formik and Yup:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at yupToFormErrors (formik.es6.js:6198)
    at formik.es6.js:5933
    at <anonymous>
yupToFormErrors @ formik.es6.js:6198
```

And I get validation errors from Yup as well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's important to also set ```enableReinitialize``` to ```true``` along side the ```initialValues``` object.

Answer (score 205):

You probably aren't defining a validation rule for the **showEmail** field.

I've done a CodeSandox to test it out and as soon as I added:

```
showEmail: yup.boolean()
```

The form started validation correctly and no error was thrown.

This is the url: https://codesandbox.io/s/74z4px0k8q

And for future this was the correct validation schema:

```
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
    showEmail: yup.boolean(),
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email()
      .when("showEmail", {
        is: true,
        then: yup.string().required("Must enter email address")
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: How would this work with three possible values for showEmail? I.e. rather than a boolean() it was a string()

Comment: You'll add a specific test to the is key using a function:
is: (emailValue) => emailValue === "some test string you want it to match"

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really have no idea how you came up with this solution but that reflects a major problem with many npm packages, i.e. 90 percent of the library documentation should be pulled from the Git issues or SO answers.

Comment: Updated codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-conditional-val-1ldmx

Comment: keep in mind, that there is "otherwise" key that is opposite to "then", where you can keep alternative validations

Comment: In a new yup `v1` and upper version you have to return schema when doing conditiona like so `then: (schema) => schema.min(5)...`

Comment: For this to now work you need to have then as a callback function.

Answer (score 84):

Formik author here...

To make `Yup.when` work properly, you would have to add `showEmail` to `initialValues` and to your Yup schema shape.

In general, when using `validationSchema`, it is best practices to ensure that all of your form's fields have initial values so that Yup can see them immediately.

The result would look like:

```
<Formik 
  initialValues={{ email: '', showEmail: false }}
  validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    showEmail: Yup.boolean(),
    email: Yup
      .string()
      .email()
      .when("showEmail", {
        is: true,
        then: Yup.string().required("Must enter email address")
      })
  })
}

/>
```

Comment: "best practice to ensure that all of you form's fields have initial values..."

A pretty common example where this doesn't hold true is number inputs. Say that you want your input to start empty. Not with zero, not with any other number. You would have to initialize this field to undefined.

Comment: What do you do when you have nested form with object like notation? So basically a field which `name` ends up being e.g. "tax[0].country"

Answer (score 42):

You can even use a function for complex cases . Function case helps for complex validations

```
validationSchema={yup.object().shape({
    showEmail: yup.boolean(),
    email: yup
      .string()
      .email()
      .when("showEmail", (showEmail, schema) => {
        if(showEmail)
          return schema.required("Must enter email address")
        return schema
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: This works for me, without typescript complaining overloading methods. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

Totally agree with @João Cunha's answer. Just a supplement for the use case of Radio button.

When we use radio button as condition, we can check value of string instead of boolean. e.g. `is: 'Phone'`

```
const ValidationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
  // This is the radio button.
  preferredContact: Yup.string()
    .required('Preferred contact is required.'),
  // This is the input field.
  contactPhone: Yup.string()
    .when('preferredContact', {
      is: 'Phone',
      then: Yup.string()
        .required('Phone number is required.'),
    }),
  // This is another input field.
  contactEmail: Yup.string()
    .when('preferredContact', {
      is: 'Email',
      then: Yup.string()
        .email('Please use a valid email address.')
        .required('Email address is required.'),
    }),

});
```

This the radio button written in ReactJS, onChange method is the key to trigger the condition checking.

```
<label>
  <input
    name="preferredContact" type="radio" value="Email"
    checked={this.state.preferredContact == 'Email'}
    onChange={() => this.handleRadioButtonChange('Email', setFieldValue)}
  />
  Email
</label>
<label>
  <input
    name="preferredContact" type="radio" value="Phone"
    checked={this.state.preferredContact == 'Phone'}
    onChange={() => this.handleRadioButtonChange('Phone', setFieldValue)}
  />
  Phone
</label>
```

And here's the callback function when radio button get changed. if we are using Formik, [setFieldValue](http://handleRadioButtonChange(value,%20setFieldValue)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20this.setState(%7B'preferredContact':%20value%7D);%20%20%20%20%20setFieldValue('preferredContact',%20value);%20%20%20%7D) is the way to go.

```
handleRadioButtonChange(value, setFieldValue) {
  this.setState({'preferredContact': value});
  setFieldValue('preferredContact', value);
}
```

Comment: You saved a lot of time

Answer (score 19):

```
email: Yup.string()
    .when(['showEmail', 'anotherField'], {
        is: (showEmail, anotherField) => {
            return (showEmail && anotherField);
        },
        then: Yup.string().required('Must enter email address')
    }),
```

Answer (score 9):

Attention anyone using Yup `v1` and upper. `v1.2` in my case.
According to the [official docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup) you have to do `(schema) => ...` in you conditions

Official Docs:
For schema with dynamic components (references, lazy, or conditions), describe requires more context to accurately return the schema description. In these cases provide options

```
import { ref, object, string, boolean } from 'yup';

let schema = object({
  isBig: boolean(),
  count: number().when('isBig', {
    is: true,
    then: (schema) => schema.min(5),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.min(0),
  }),
});

schema.describe({ value: { isBig: true } });
```

Answer (score 5):

for typescript using this

```
reasonContractNotDone: yup.string().when('isContractDone', {
  is: false,
  then(schema) {
    return schema.required('Must enter email address');
  },
}),
```

NOT like below!

```
reasonContractNotDone: yup.string().when('isContractDone', {
  is: false,
  then: yup.string().required("Must enter email address")
}),
```

Answer (score 3):

it works for me very well :

```
   Yup.object().shape({
    voyageStartDate:Yup.date(),
    voyageEndDate:Yup.date()
        .when(
            'voyageStartDate',
            (voyageStartDate, schema) => (moment(voyageStartDate).isValid() ? schema.min(voyageStartDate) : schema),
        ),
})
```

Comment: This is so close to what I'm looking for. If you want to make sure END > START, how would you access the `end` value in the `.when` here? I only want to compare if `start` is set.

Answer (score 2):

Checking for a specific value without using the function notation:

If select `choice` has value `date`, then input field `date` is required:

```
availableDate: yup.string().when('choice', {
    is: (v) => v === 'date',
    then: (schema) => schema.required('date is required')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

### I use yup with vee-validate

[vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/v4/guide/composition-api/validation#validation-schemas-with-yup)

here is the sample code from project

```
const schema = yup.object({
    first_name: yup.string().required().max(45).label('Name'),
    last_name: yup.string().required().max(45).label('Last name'),
    email: yup.string().email().required().max(255).label('Email'),
    self_user: yup.boolean(),
    company_id: yup.number()
        .when('self_user', {
            is: false,
            then: yup.number().required()
        })
})
const { validate, resetForm } = useForm({
    validationSchema: schema,
    initialValues: {
        self_user: true
    }
})

const {
    value: self_user
} = useField('self_user')
const handleSelfUserChange = () => {
    self_user.value = !self_user.value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This Code Works For ME Try To use It

const validation = () => {
   try {
    let userSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    date: Yup.string().required(),
    city: Yup.string().required(),
    gender: Yup.string().required(),
    email: Yup.string()
      .matches(
        /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|. 
   (".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA- 
   Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/,
      )
      .nullable(true),
    userName: Yup.string().min(3),
  });
  userSchema.validateSync({
    email: email,
    userName: userName,
    gender: gender.name,
    city: city.name,
    date: date,
   });
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
   setError({
     userName: '',
     email: '',
     gender: '',
     city: '',
     date: '',
     [error.path]: error.name,
    });
   }
 };
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please refer to [how do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for some pointers on how to improve this answer. For example, it could use some explanation of your code and why it works/why it resolves the question. After all, we are not a code-writing service, but a place to learn.