# How to set up yup validation conditionals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, validation, yup

I have a set of data that i'm tring to validate; It have two fields: "citiesProvided" and "servicesProvided" they are dependent of "LegalCorrespondenceService" that is a array with just one string with the value "true" or "false" Like represented below:

[Structure of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiEDZ.png)

When "true" the validation of the other fields need to be done, otherwise with "false" not.
How can i do this conditional validation with yup?

this the code that I had no result:

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
          
          JuridicCorrespondence: Yup.array().of(
            Yup.object().shape({
              LegalCorrespondenceService: Yup.array()
                .of(Yup.boolean())
                .length(1, 'Escolha uma opção.'),
              citiesProvided: Yup.array().when(['LegalCorrespondenceService'], {
                is: 'true',
                then: Yup.array()
                  .of(Yup.string())
                  .length(1, 'Escolha uma opção.')
              }),

              servicesProvided: Yup.array().when(['LegalCorrespondenceService'], {
                is: 'true',
                then: Yup.array()
                  .of(Yup.string())
                  .length(1, 'Escolha uma opção.')
              }),
            })
          )
        });
```

Comment: In your example, LegalCorrespondenceService is an array of string literals "true" or "false" and not boolean.

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69408030/1235675)