# Formik min date max date validation if Max date < min date i wanna to showing error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup, react-fullstack

I have 2 input,from date to date and if user enter from date and to date while,to date don't < from date if happened i wanna to shwo error. I'm using FORMIK and YUP package

While I'm tried many method at the time didn't show error but if i didn't use when function, that time getting value on other hand some tims getting error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Yup validation with two fields related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49522347/yup-validation-with-two-fields-related)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.