# Formik with checkbox field and and a dependent field

Tags: reactjs, formik

I want to create a form that contain a checkbox field. Initially, the checkbox is unchecked and a field under it is disabled. If all other required fields are fill correctly, the submit button will be enable for submitting the form. Once the user checked the checkbox, the field under it will be enabled (this is a required field if enabled) thus, submit button needs to be disabled again. If unchecked again, submit button will enabled again. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65715811/yup-useformik-conditional-required-field-based-on-some-parameter/65715969 check if this helps

Comment: Thanks but it's not relevant

Comment: Ok. can you please add a sample code snippet describing the issue?