# Yup conditional base validation with react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup, react-hook-form

I tried to do the validation using yup with react hook form. When the first checkbox is enabled I want to make the second checkbook required. When the second checkbox is enabled remaining fields should be required.

```
yup.object().shape({
  firstName: yup.string().required(),
  age: yup.number().required().positive().integer(),
  website: yup.string().url(),
  h1: yup.boolean(),
  h2: yup.boolean().test("required", "h2 required", function validator(val) {
    const { h1 } = this.parent;
    return h1;
  })
```

and my codesandbox link is https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-validationschema-forked-pmcgo?file=/src/index.js:178-471

How to fix this issue

Comment: Please check this answer [Conditional Validation in Yup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394391/conditional-validation-in-yup)

Answer (score 0):

As both `h1` and `h2` are in the same level of the object, you can use `when` on the `h2`.

From `yup` [docs](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedvalidateatpath-string-value-any-options-object-promiseany-validationerror):

```js
let schema = object({
  foo: array().of(
    object({
      loose: boolean(),
      bar: string().when('loose', {
        is: true,
        otherwise: (s) => s.strict(),
      }),
    }),
  ),
});
```